# Deploying Taipy on Heroku gives Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: python, heroku, taipy

I am using Taipy and I need to deploy my app on Heroku. I keep getting error "Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch". Here  is an image of the log file below.
[image: logs]

my **Procfile**

```
web: python main.py --host=0.0.0.0
echo ${GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS} > /app/google-credentials.json
```

I have included the main.py script. The last line of the script contains the rn function which is used to run the `taipy` server on default port `5000`. I don't know how to adjust the `run()` function to accept heroku default port.
**Edit: main.py **

```py
. . .

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Core().run()
    scenario = tp.create_scenario(scenario_cfg)
    scenario_search = tp.create_scenario(text_search_scenario_cfg)
    scenario_search_image = tp.create_scenario(image_search_scenario_cfg)
    Gui(pages = pages).run()
```

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: `Procfile`s aren't scripts. You can't dump arbitrary code into one and expect it to run. In any case, you'll need to use the port Heroku gives you. What's in `main.py`? Do you attempt to set the port there?

Comment: @Chris ,  main.py is the  file can contains the `run` command to run the server.  I have updated the code to contain the main.py script .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle web requests on Heroku, your service needs to listen on the right port. This is [provided at runtime via the `PORT` environment variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/runtime-principles#web-servers):

> On Heroku, apps are completely self-contained and do not rely on runtime injection of a webserver into the execution environment to create a web-facing service. Each web process simply binds to a port, and listens for requests coming in on that port. The [port to bind to](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#web-dynos) is assigned by Heroku as the `PORT` environment variable.

This can be done in `main.py`, but the easiest solution is probably to [add the `--port` option](https://docs.taipy.io/en/release-2.1/manuals/gui/configuration/#configuring-the-gui-instance) to the `web` process in your `Procfile`:

```
web: python main.py --host=0.0.0.0 --port=$PORT
```

---

Note that the second line in your `Procfile` won't do anything. `Procfile`s aren't scripts, so you can't run arbitrary commands like that. They [define process types](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile).

If you can set your credentials some other way (e.g. read them directly from the environment variable instead of dumping that variable to a file and reading the file), I suggest you do that. If you *really* need that file to exist, you may want to consider writing a wrapper shell script to create the file and start your application.

Comment: Thank you , but it seems to work only when dynos = 7$/month. It does'nt work on a free plan. Thank you for helping me with issue.

Comment: @ForchaPearl, [Heroku no longer offers free services](https://blog.heroku.com/next-chapter).